# How to use exists condition in select query in postgresql?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, exists

I want to check whether the emp_id and date has been already there in both bill_item and bill_item_temp tables or not? if not exists then i have to do insert?

```py
s = CONN.cursor()                 
query = """insert into bill_item (id,product_name,price,create_date,emp_id)
           select %s,%s,%s,%s,%s where not exists ( select 1 from bill_item where emp_id = %s and 
           select 1 from bill_item_ref where emp_id = %s);"""
s.execute(query,(id,product_name,price,create_date,emp_id,));
```

table: bill_item

```
id product_name price create_date                   emp_id
1  rice         10    2021-03-09 10:10:10.231321    12345
2  tea          10    2021-03-09 08:10:10.231321    22345
```

table: bill_item_temp

```
id product_name   price create_date                   emp_id
1  drinks         10    2021-03-09 10:10:10.231321    67345
2  snacks         10    2021-03-09 08:10:10.231321    92345
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: could you give a alternate solution for how to check the 2 select queries by using exists at the same time

Answer (score 1):

The `FROM` clause is missing in this query:

```sql
select %s,%s,%s,%s,%s where not exists(...)
```

And the `SELECT` statement has incorrect syntax here:

```sql
where not exists ( select 1 from bill_item where emp_id = %s and 
                   select 1 from bill_item_ref where emp_id = %s);
```

You can't have `AND` between two `SELECT` statements.

Either use `UNION`/`UNION ALL` or use separate `EXISTS` for individual `SELECT` statement.

This is how you can use `UNION ALL`:

```sql
where not exists ( select 1 from bill_item where emp_id = %s UNION ALL 
                   select 1 from bill_item_ref where emp_id = %s);
```

And this is how you can use separate `EXISTS` for individual `SELECT` statement:

```sql
where not exists (select 1 from bill_item where emp_id = %s) and
      not exists (select 1 from bill_item_ref where emp_id = %s);
```

Comment: Could you please give me the code by using union.. i am a fresher i dono how to use

Comment: @pythoncoder That depends on your use case here. Do you want both entries to be present? What should happen if there is an entry in `bill_item` but it's missing in  `bill_item_ref` (and vice versa)?

Comment: either one of the tables has the record means (exists) means then insertion should not happen.

Comment: @pythoncoder I have updated my answer to include `UNION ALL`.

Comment: This is a Python exception. Can you try executing this query directly in Postgres?

Comment: sir, i want to insert into bill_item table if the emp_id, create_date values  not exists in bill_item and bill_item_temp both the tables.. please suggest any idea sir